# 301 redirects and wordpress pretty permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am  moving from an old php based site to a new one based on wordpress. In the process we are getting rid of quite a few unnecessary pages.

However some of the pages are showing on google, and I want to avoid 403 or 404 errors by using 301 redirects to pages now containing the same info on the new site.

My current .htaccess shows:

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 53

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and I was wondering what the best way to do 301 redirects is? putting them before or after the code just gives a 404 error.

Comment: What is the code you tried to put before and after it?

Comment: redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.website.com/new.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a rule similar to this before the index.php rewrite rules should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can put a bunch of RewriteCond's before it to catch only those pages with issues.

For the specific case you posted in the comments, this rule works:

```
RewriteRule ^why-choose-us.* about-us [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ok, but where do i put the old/new page details? where the star is for old?

Comment: Can you give an example of old/new pages? Then I can show you how to modify the rule above for your case.

Comment: they are similar to this... old page - `domain.co.uk/why-choose-us.php` new page - `domain.co.uk/about-us`

Comment: Well, for that case,

    RewriteRule ^why-choose-us.* about-us [R=301,L]

Answer (score 2):

This should work;

redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.website.com/new.htm

Comment: like i said above, this does not work...it just redirects to the wordpress 404 page. i want it to redirect to the new page